# Does prometheus round off values for the divsion operator?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a query like sum(query1)/sum(query2).
When I manually do the division, it gives 1.98 but in result it says 2.
Is that doing it automatically ?

Answer (score 3):

Prometheus stores time series values as 64-bit floating-point numbers and preforms all the PromQL calculations with [floating-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic), which may result in some precision loss. See, for example, [the result returned by Prometheus for 0.1+0.2](http://demo.robustperception.io:9090/graph?g0.expr=0.1%2B0.2&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h). See also [these explanations](https://0.30000000000000004.com/). But this precision loss is invisible in most practical calculations.

So the answer to the original questions: Prometheus doesn't round off values for the division operator and for any other PromQL operations. But some precision loss may happen in edge cases due to floating-point math.

Prometheus provides [round()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#round) function, which can be used for rounding the results to the given decimal digit. For example, `round(vector(1/3), 0.1)` would return `0.3`. The [vector()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#vector) function is needed for Prometheus only due to PromQL implementation details. It isn't needed for other Prometheus-compatible query engines such as [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) at [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this rounding happens on your visualization side, like Grafana. I've seen crazy decimals in Prometheus and used `round()` (see https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#round) to force rounding in some occasions.

Or did you run the query in Prometheus Graph and saw this behaviour?

Comment: Could you show a bit more detail about the actually query and actual values?